# In search of an application to convert list of events into individual ICS files

Tags: calendar

I have a google sheet with a list of details about upcoming events. I want to convert each row into an individual ICS file that someone can click on to download and add into their calendar.

Answer (score 3):

I found a non-web application solution, native for Microsoft Windows: [*CSV-to-ICS*](https://csv-to-ics.com/)

Imports data files in [comma-separated values format (CSV)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), or [tab-delimited values format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values). Most any spreadsheet or database can generate such files, including *Microsoft Excel* and *LibreOffice*.

Free of cost.